# Vlookup from multiple criteria to display nearest answer

Tags: arrays, excel, excel-formula, formula

I was hoping someone can help me. I have hit a solid wall.

I have a table with product information included and I am building a calculator which should spit out a number of options based on set criteria which is in the table. I am failing at just pulling through a code. I feel rather embarassed asking about how to do a vlookup here. But basically I have a vlookup which depends on multiple criteria and for the calc to cough out the nearest match (if applicable) based on this criteria.

```
Criteria 1 = Product

Criteria 2 = Type

Criteria 3 = Height

Criteria 4 = Min
```

I have created a search key in the table to concatenate all of these columns and then done a vlookup, which is `=Vlookup(Criteria1 & Criteria2 & Criteria3 & Criteria4, Table Data, Code Required)` But this does not appear to be giving me results, it either coughs out an error or the incorrect product. Below is my data and my calc I am hoping to complete. Can someone please help?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Please insert code/data between code tags, use perhaps a table generator to help with formatting, not as images.

Comment: Also, closest match on what? A combined key is unlikely to help in that instance. Is it closest min value?

Comment: The closest Match under the min value.... So if I put in Product1 into the search, I only want the code to look at Product1 in the table, then I want it to look next at the Height, so at the top of the calc 300 it will look in the table at Product1 and height of 300, then I want it to look at Type which would then narrow the table to Product1 Height 300 and Type 11 on the top row of the calc, then get the closest match to the Min of 1000 which in the table is Product1, Type 11, Height 300, the min is 803 and the code is P130180G. I hope that makes sense

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is an example looking for a closest match on Min. It demonstrates the principle so you can extend.

The closest match formula part is:

```
MATCH(MIN(ABS(E2:E4-K2)),ABS(E2:E4-K2),0))
```

Column E for column with Min values in. And K2 for target Min. This is an array formula entered with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>.  You would adjust the range of E2:E4.

The multiple criteria part is using:

```
=MATCH(lookup_value_1&lookup_value_2&lookup_value_3, lookup_array_1&lookup_array_2&lookup_array_3, match_type)
```

Where you are concantenating your parameters and searching for a match of the concatenation of those parameters in the table (you could do this against the key column if the key is made up of the same parameters.)

Overall formula with some test data (using one estimate figure):

```
=INDEX(F:F,MATCH(K1&K5&J5&INDEX(E2:E4,MATCH(MIN(ABS(E2:E4-K2)),ABS(E2:E4-K2),0)),B:B&C:C&D:D&E:E,0))
```

Above entered combined formula remember is an array formula so entered with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> . You can reduce the ranges from entire columns to only those rows holding data.

---

**Data data:**

I am not typing all that out from picture so here is a quick n dirty

[image: TEST DATA]

Comment: Thanks @QHarr that has helped immensely. Sorry for the image, I could not see how to attach the table.

Comment: That's ok. Someone had to tell me! I use this https://www.tablesgenerator.com/markdown_tables . You can paste your table from excel into it (there is a dropdown option). Then copy to clipboard, paste in the question. Highlight it and press Ctrl + K to put between code tags,

Answer (score 0):

I tried with the QHarr's solution but it didn't work with all the rows.

My solution is:

1. Add a column with:

=IF(E2 < $K$2, E2, 0) and copy for all rows

2. In L5 create the formula:

{=INDEX(F2:F19,MATCH($K$1&K5&$J$5&INDEX(E2:E19,MATCH(MAX(SI(B2:B19=$K$1,1,0)*IF(C2:C19=K5,1,0)*IF(D2:D19=$J$5,1,0)*G2:G19,0),E2:E19,0)),B2:B19&C2:C19&D2:D19&E2:E19,0))}

3. Copy the formula to L6 and L7

[Excel exercise printscreen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sbVEQ.jpg)

Comment: Thanks, I noticed as I added more and more products it was beginning to fail. I managed to work it out with the following '{=INDEX(Calc!$I$2:$I$189,MATCH(Output!$H$7,IF(Calc!$B$2:$B$189=Output!A12,Calc!$H$2:$H$189),1))}'

Answer (score 0):

Originally marked this as answered and it did work initially but as I added more products it began to fail. I did manage to (after much trial and error) find a simple solution `{=INDEX(Calc!$I$2:$I$189,MATCH(Output!$H$7,IF(Calc!$B$2:$B$189=Output!A12,Calc!$H$2:$H$189),1))}`

Comment: Please provide a workbook with the data in and I will update if there is a problem :-)